# Undefined offset em laço de repetição no PHP

Tags: php, api

Estou usando a API do twitch.tv. Estou pegando todas as *lives* de "fifa17" e listando todos os nomes dos canais que estão fazendo esta *live* com esse jogo, na URL tem o limite de 100 resultados ou seja 100 nomes, fiz um `for` para listar todos os nomes, o `for` mostra 89 nomes e resto dos nomes que falta ele da o erro `Undefined offset: 89`

```
<?php

$api2 = file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?client_id=g5ynk8n0llmefg9m70ruyg36bbt6si&query=fifa17&limit=100");

$defuse = json_decode($api2);

if($defuse == null){
    echo "erro";
}else{

    $total_lives=$defuse->_total;

    echo "Toltal de Lives:  ".$total_lives."</br>";

    for($i=0;$i<=99;$i++)
        echo $defuse->streams[$i]->channel->name."</br>";
}

?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O número 100 indica ao webservice o limite e não a quantidade exata que deve retornar. Por isso, não deve esperar que sempre retornará 100 resultados.

Para resolver, use o laço de repetição `foreach()`

```
for($i=0;$i<=99;$i++)
    echo $defuse->streams[$i]->channel->name."</br>";
```

Ficaria assim:

```
foreach($defuse->streams as $v)
    echo $v->channel->name."</br>";
```

Comment: Nossa parceiro muito obrigado pela ajuda deu certo aqui e também obrigado pela explicação que Deus te abençoe.